# where is placed the this pointer and and when memory is allocated for it?

Tags: c++, memory-management, this

Why pointer to the virtual function table affects the size of the class , but this pointer does not affect the size of the class ? where is placed the this pointer and 
when memory is allocated for it?

Comment: You'll have plenty of answers on this below. A better question that will really bake your noodle is, where is the virtual-method table for a given-instance of a polymorphic object type *stored*? Does each object have one (or do they even need to have one) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is passed as an implicit parameter and therefore it is not stored inside of the object. When you write:

```
struct X
{
    void f( int i );
};

X x;
x.f( 42 );
```

You can think of it like this:

```
void f( X* const this, int i ); // of course this would be illegal as "this" is a keyword

f( &x, 42 );
```

So the `this`-pointer is coming from where the method is called.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer to the virtual function table is stored in the object, but `this` is actually a hidden *parameter* of member functions. In effect, when you have this:

```
class X
{
  void foo(int bar) const;
};

int main()
{
  X x;
  x.foo(7);
}
```

Then the compiler will implicitly transform it to something like this (pseudo-code):

```
class X
{
  static void foo(const X * const this, int bar);
};

int main()
{
  X x;
  X::foo(&x, 7);
}
```

Note that I am only showing the pseudo-code for illustration purposes. You can conceptually imagine it like that, but it's not what is actually happening.

Comment: I actually preferred Daniel Frey's idea of illustrating with a non-const method; it makes it clearer where the `const` in the "static" example comes from (instead of having 2 `const`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point. I will keep it as it is, though, to offer more versatility in the answers.

Comment: Why const X * const this ? Instead, it would have been, X * const this.

Comment: @Subhajit Well, I used a `const` member function as the example, so this leads to `const X * const`. Upvote Daniel's answer if you prefer the non-const example.

Answer (score 1):

`this` pointer is implicitly placed on the stack (it's like an argument to the method). So when you call `obj->foo()` you're implicitly passing obj into method foo. The compiler gives you access to that argument through `this`.

In general there can't be a need to store this pointer inside the object anyway. It would be redundant (i.e. if you could get hold of the object its address is already available to you).

vTable however is a different story. Which vtable an object points to can't be known at compile time and there's no separate implicit argument either. This requires dedicated space in the object itself.

Comment: That's not true for VC++ (and probably not for a lot of other compilers).  With VC++, `this` is typically in the register ECX, with Sun CC (on Sparc), it will be in the register `i0`, etc.

Comment: Well it's conceptually on stack. Whether ECX is used or not is more like an optimization. There's no restriction on using ECX for other arguments (static methods for example). That doesn't mean you have to include that detail in explaining how method arguments are pushed on the stack.

Comment: As an rvalue, it's conceptually nowhere.  Something like the pointer behind a reference (which the standard also pretends doesn't exist).  Or like the results of `x + y`, when `x` and `y` are integral types.

Answer (score 1):

Like 'this' pointer, the vptr depends a instance not the class.

Comment: This does not address why the v-pointer is stored within the object and yet `this` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere.  The `this` pointer isn't an lvalue, and doesn't occupy
memory as such.  It's sort of like asking where the results of
`x + y` reside (where `x` and `y` are `int`).  Depending on the
implementation, where it will really reside will vary: VC++, for
example, tends to keep it in the register ECX (although this may
vary when optimization is used); Sun CC for Sparc puts it in the
register `i0`, etc.  It's *not* a member, even implicit, of the
class.  It's probably best thought of as an argument to the
function, although many compilers will treat it special, and
unlike normal arguments, it's not an lvalue.